# How to change letter spacing / condense letters together

Tags: fontsize

I'm starting up with LaTeX today in order to be able to produce better-looking PDFs for university assignments. I'm working through a list of small exercises, handed out by a volunteer professor, and a certain one has stalled me a bit.

This is what I'm supposed to have in my output:

[image]

So, to tackle it, here's the code I wrote:

```
\section{\gt Άσκηση 1η} \gt
\fontsize{14}{16.8} \selectfont Α
\fontsize{16}{19.2} \selectfont Β
\fontsize{20}{24}   \selectfont Γ
\fontsize{24}{28.8} \selectfont Δ
\fontsize{28}{33.6} \selectfont Ε
\fontsize{32}{38.4} \selectfont Ζ
\fontsize{36}{43.2} \selectfont Η
\fontsize{40}{48}   \selectfont Θ 
\fontsize{44}{52.8} \selectfont Ι
\fontsize{40}{48}   \selectfont κ
\fontsize{36}{43.2} \selectfont λ
\fontsize{32}{38.4} \selectfont μ
\fontsize{28}{33.6} \selectfont ν
\fontsize{24}{28.8} \selectfont ξ
\fontsize{20}{24}   \selectfont ο
\fontsize{16}{19.2} \selectfont π
```

The output is, of course, the following:

[image]

Obviously I still have to do something for the letter spacing, condense them together. I've gone through at least 6 similar topics on `tex.stackexchange` and I haven't been able to solve it using the already proposed solutions.

Any help related to my question or with any problems in my code (maybe I've written redundant lines) would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using TeXStudio and MiKTeX.

Comment: You have a 2 word spaces (from end of line, and after `\fontsize{}{}`) after each letter: also you don't want to change the baselineskip after each letter (it has no effect anyway as the same baseline is used for the whole paragraph

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fixed that right now, I keep forgetting this isn't a compiler that ignores whitespaces. Also added {}s at the end of statements.

I'm still in need of spacing, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is homework, so I'll only give a hint: no `\fontsize` command is used, just standard documented commands.

[image]

It's obviously an exercise on the font size changing commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\begin{document}
{\itshape
\tiny Α%
\scriptsize Β%
\footnotesize Γ%
\small Δ%
\normalsize Ε%
\large Ζ%
\Large Η%
\LARGE Θ%
\huge Ι%
\huge κ%
\LARGE λ%
\Large μ%
\large ν%
\normalsize ξ%
\small ο%
\footnotesize π%
\scriptsize ρ%
\tiny ς}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you play with \tiny, \footscript etc?

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis Exactly.

Comment: I have noticed something. At the end of your letters you place a single %. Without it, my letters have spacing between them. With it, they stick together.

I was curious about that.

Answer (score 6):

Manually changing the spacing between words is usually not required or recommended. I mention the spacing between *words* because, as David noted, you are adding unwanted spaces between your letters, and therefore each is treated as a word:

```
\fontsize{14}{16.8}[*space*]\selectfont Α[*space*]
\fontsize{16}{19.2}[*space*]\selectfont Β[*space*]
...
```

Also, as you already figured, a more sensible approach is to use the built-in size commands.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\textit{\scriptsize A\footnotesize B\small G\normalsize D\large E\Large Z\LARGE H\huge J\Huge I\Huge k\huge l\Large m\large n\normalsize x\small o\footnotesize p\scriptsize r\tiny s}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question inspires me to create the following command, called `\wavytext`:

```
\usepackage{intcalc}

\newcounter{countwavytext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@wavychar}[1]{%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=0\tiny#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=1\scriptsize#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=2\footnotesize#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=3\small#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=4\normalsize#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=5\large#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=6\Large#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=7\LARGE#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=8\huge#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=9\Huge#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=10\huge#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=11\LARGE#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=12\Large#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=13\large#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=14\normalsize#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=15\small#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=16\footnotesize#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=17\scriptsize#1\else%
\ifnum\intcalcMod{\value{countwavytext}}{19}=18\tiny#1\else%
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
\stepcounter{countwavytext}}
\newcommand{\wavytext}[1]{%
\@tempswafalse
    \@for\next:=#1\do
    {\if@tempswa\else%
    \@tempswatrue\fi%
    \@wavychar{\next}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The effect of the command is demonstrate as follow:

```
\textit{\wavytext{A,B,Γ,Δ,E,Ζ,Η,Θ,I,Κ,Λ,M,N,Ξ,O,Π,Ρ,Σ,Τ}}

\textit{\wavytext{α,β,γ,δ,ε,ζ,η,θ,ι,κ,λ,μ,ν,ξ,ο,π,ρ,σ,τ}}
```

produces
[image]

I am not satisfy by the current definition, though, as each character must be separated by `,`. One possible solution is to redefine `\@forloop` and `\@iforloop`. But I guess that creates more troubles than it solves...

Comment: If you were on XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX the Greek characters would be single tokens; in (pdf)LaTeX they could be two or more tokens (multibyte in UTF-8) so a general solution without separating commas would be much more complicated: Greek letters are two byte long, others can be one, three or four.

Comment: How nice is that!